# Electron Atom File Type Association in Windows Registry

Tags: node.js, registry, electron, winreg

I'm building an app in Electron boilerplate and need to associate a custom file type in the Windows registry and Mac plist in order to open these files in my app.

The Mac seems fairly straight forward and have found some info from others that have managed to do this so not too concerned with Mac.

On the Windows side my first thought is to just use the winreg npm to write the keys to the registry.  Seems easy enough in theory, the only problem is the docs for how to use winreg is pretty sparce at best.

I'm able to run the example code fine and spit out the autorun programs so it's installed and working fine and reading/outputting stuff makes sense to me.  What I can't seem to find much info on is actually writing new keys to the registry, I'm assuming I would use create(cb) to do this but I can't seem to get it to work and honestly just the create(callback) structure doesn't really seem to make sense since there's really no logic there to pass the key, I've tried create('key to add', function() { but I'm sure that's not how you're supposed to do it hence it doesn't work lol.

Basically all I really want to do is something like this (taken from c# example):

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mycompany.appname.v1\shell\open\command", null, @"c:\path\to\app.exe \"%1\"");
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.myextension", null, "mycompany.appname.v1");
```

How to actually add new registry key values within node winreg?

Answer (score 2):

We can access registry using command prompt in windows. I tried using those commands it worked fine, created a child-process and executed the command, if we type `reg/?` we can see all the ways we can use that command. you can see detailed about reg here [registry commands]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg . In electron we can use it like `require(child-process).exec('REG ADD HKLM\Software\MYKEY');` (this adds a key to software).

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of your C# example would look something like this (using promises, since I don't like nesting callbacks):

```
const setKeys = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const regKey = new Registry({
    hive: Registry.HKCU,
    key: '\\Software\\Classes\\mycompany.appname.v1\\shell\\open\\command'
  });
  regKey.set(
    Registry.DEFAULT_VALUE, Registry.REG_SZ, 'c:\\path\\to\\app.exe "%1"',
    error => (error ? reject(error) : resolve())
  );
})
.then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) {
  const regKey = new Registry({
    hive: Registry.HKCU,
    key: '\\Software\\Classes\\.myextension'
  });
  regKey.set(
    Registry.DEFAULT_VALUE, Registry.REG_SZ, 'mycompany.appname.v1',
    error => (error ? reject(error) : resolve())
  );
})
.then(() => console.log('Extension registered!'))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```